# Traffic Light Sequence Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been asked to make a traffic light sequence but I don't know what the error in my work is. When I click the button, none of the images will switch and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. It just stays on the default traffic light image. The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<body>

<h1> <u> T</u></h1>

<img id="Lights" src="TrafficLights.png" alt="Traffic Lights" width="600" height ="500"> 

<button onclick="ChangeLights()">Switch lights</button> 

<script>
var TrafficLights = new array();
var TrafficLights = ["TrafficLights.png", "RedLights.png", "YellowLights.png", "GreenLights.png"]
var index = 0;
    function ChangeLights() {
        index = index + 1;
        if (index == TrafficLights.length)
            index = 0;
    document.getElementById("Lights").src = TrafficLights[index];
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to define `var TrafficLights` *twice*.  Also `new array();` isn't valid JavaScript code.

Comment: You don't know what the error in your work is? Open the developer console and see the errors that this is throwing. Little bit of effort goes a long way!

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Have you tried putting a console.log statement in your ChangeLights function to see if it is called when you click on the button?

Comment: Hi cloud007, we don't delete posts here, unless they turn out to be unanswerable. Since you received an answer below, I think the system may disallow deletion. We like to keep Q&A pagesanyway, since they may be helpful to future readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var TrafficLights = new array();
```

This line is causing all of your errors.  Remove it and everything should work.

You do not need this line since the next line is:

```
var TrafficLights = ["TrafficLights.png", "RedLights.png", "YellowLights.png", "GreenLights.png"]
```

This declares and defines `TrafficLights` to be an array, there is no need for the previous line.

NOTE: If you want to make a blank array, do `var TrafficLights = [];` (preferred) or `var TrafficLights = new Array;` (note the uppercase 'A').

Comment: Thankyou :) however even after deleting this line, it still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/z5jy8nph/  Open the JavaScript console and see if there any any errors.

Comment: I'm not sure what was going on, but I reopened and redid the .html file and just deleted that line and it works now. Thankyou! It must of just been something wrong with the one before I reopened it

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting one. So there's an exception with assigning `new array()` assignment, since `array` is not a valid thing, as shown in the previous answers:

```
var TrafficLights = new array();
VM276:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:25
```

One would assume that the code below this error did not get evaluated...

...however, clicking the button **actually invokes the `ChangeLights` function correctly**, which yields a different error:

```
VM81:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at ChangeLights (VM81:66)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM83:56)
```

So the `ChangeLights` function gets declared, while `TrafficLights` did not. Why is that?

I think this is because the `TrafficLights` variable never gets declared because of the first error, yet the function is available **because it was [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) before the first exception is even thrown**!